# CURL NTML authentication is working from command line but not working with php script

Tags: php, curl

I need to call a .net web service. This web service requires NTLM authentication. For that, I wrote some code with NTLM authentication. And I am trying to connect using curl with NTLM authentication. But from php script I am getting 401 error. I tried with different header content (xml and html). Please help.

**Below is the command line which is working.**

```
curl http://qtskofaxweb01.etch.com/TotalAgility/Services/Sdk/JobService.svc?wsdl -v --ntlm --negotiate -u kofax:Jagadish6^
```

**Below is my PHP script which is not working**

```
$path = 'http://qtskofaxweb01.etch.com/TotalAgility/Services/Sdk/JobService.svc?wsdl';
$user = 'kofax';
$password = 'Jagadish6^';

$ch = curl_init($path);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/xml';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/xml';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$password);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

**Out put is given below**

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://qtskofaxweb01.etch.com/TotalAgility/Services/Sdk/JobService.svc?wsdl
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 401
    [header_size] => 657
    [request_size] => 546
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 1
    [total_time] => 0.003738
    [namelookup_time] => 1.4E-5
    [connect_time] => 1.5E-5
    [pretransfer_time] => 1.7E-5
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 1293
    [speed_download] => 345906
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 1293
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.002228
    [redirect_time] => 0.001484
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )
```

```
[primary_ip] => 10.10.3.40
[redirect_url] =>
```

)

`string '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;mar'... (length=1293)`

Answer (score 0):

please try it..

```
$url="http://qtskofaxweb01.etch.com/TotalAgility/Services/Sdk/JobService.svc?wsdl";

    $user = 'kofax';
    $password = 'Jagadish6^';

    $parameters=array();

    class Emp {
      public $user  = "";
      public $password   = "";
   }
   $e = new Emp();
   $e->user = $user ;
   $e->password   = $password ;

    $parameters['user']=$e;
    $parameters=json_encode($parameters);

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    if($output === false)
    {
        echo "Error Number:".curl_errno($ch)."<br>";
        echo "Error String:".curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    $obj = json_decode($output, TRUE);
```

Comment: thanks @jaydeep but now I am getting blank page. Noting is coming inside output variable.